# ssis conditional split not executing all conditions

Tags: ssis, conditional-split

In the SSIS I have the conditions seen in the image.  When I run the package all conditions process except the ActivityChange.  If I run the package again Activity Change is executed.  Both RecordChange and ActivityChange feed to an OLE DB Command that does an update.  In my testing I am using one record where the activity date and record id are being updated.  Does that affect how the split is processed?  If so what is another way I can ensure the activitychange is processed?

[image: SSIS Conditional Split]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A record that flows into a *Conditional Split* transformation will only take one exit which is the output with the first matching condition. That's why a *Conditional Split* usually is configured with conditions that are mutually exclusive.

If more than one condition can be true and you want to process them all, you will have to use several *Conditional Split* transformations, either as a sequence (with the "processing" tasks in between) or in parallel (with a preceding *Multicast* transformation).

Comment: That did it!  A little tedious but it gets the job done.